# Change ID CSS based on conditional

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a NavBar and having issues when this mobile button is expanded or not. I'm trying to work on this conditional statement however the if check only goes to the 'if' statement and not the 'else'.

There's currently no CSS for #logo-click but 100% width gets added when clicked, so that part works. However doesnt go away when checked again, just stays at 100%.

Not sure what I am missing.

```
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">Test </a>  


     <div class="site-logo">
        <header id="logo-click"><a href="#top"></a></header>
     </div>
     </div>

   function myFunction() {    
      var m = document.getElementById("logo-click");
      if (m.style.width = '100%'){
        m.style.width = '100%';
      }else {
        m.style.width = '0%';
      }
```

Comment: This `m.style.width = '100%'` is not a comparison, but an assignment instead. It should be `m.style.width === '100%'`.

Comment: Watch out your conditional expression

Comment: Note that if `m.style.width` is already equal to `'100%'`, there's no point setting it to `'100%'` again.

Comment: Oh conditional ordering. Got it to work without the === just the order of the if statement. Thank you.

Comment: You could simplify your logic by just writing `if (m.style.width !== '100%') m.style.width = 0;`.

Comment: if (m.style.width === '100%'){

Answer (score 0):

So to fix it you can just change the '=' to a .'===' but honestly what I would do in this case is rely mostly on css since you are essentially toggling css attributes. You can do this pretty easily like so in vanilla javascript...

### CSS

```
#logo-click {
    /* Regular old css */
}
#logo-click.closed {
    width: 0;
}
```

### JS

```
function toggleNav() {
    document.getElementById('logo-click').classList.toggle('closed');
}
```